# What song is being played during the mission Uninvited (Act 2, Mission 9)?

Tags: watch-dogs, game-music-identification

What song is being played during the mission Uninvited (Act 2, Mission 9)?

The mission involves setting up an ambush for the Viceroy hit-men.

I tried to use the Song Sneak app, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The song you are referring to is C.R.E.A.M. (Cash Rules Everything Around Me) by the Wu-Tang Clan.

After completing the mission, you unlock the song.